# structure viewModel for RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm learning MVVM and RxSwift and I want to bind all the object from the UI. I try to create a viewModel but the compiler pop up an error, am I create the view model wrong? this is my code and UI I want to bind.

[image: setting]

> Cannot use instance member 'BasicInfoViewModel' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

```
    struct BasicInfoViewModel {

    let infos = PublishSubject<InfoResult>()

    let selectedImage: Observable<UIImage>
    let fullname: Observable<String>
    let phoneNumber: Observable<String>
    let email: Observable<String>
    let placeOfBirth: Observable<String>
    let dateOfBirth: Observable<String>
    let religion: Observable<String>

    var isValid: Observable<Bool> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(fullname.asObservable(), phoneNumber.asObservable(), email.asObservable(), placeOfBirth.asObservable(), dateOfBirth.asObservable(), religion.asObservable()).map { $0.0.count > 0 }
    }
}

    class BasicInfoViewController: UITableViewController {

        var viewModel = BasicInfoViewModel()
    }
```

Comment: Its because you declared property in struct and haven't initialised them so you cant create instance of struct simply using `BasicInfoViewModel()` you have to pass initial values like `BasicInfoViewModel(selectedImage: <#Observable<UIImage>#>, fullname: <#Observable<String>#>, phoneNumber: <#Observable<String>#>....`

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your BasicInfoViewModel inside the view did load method and pass the inputs in from the views.